# Почему объект не наследует свойство своего прототипа?

Tags: javascript

```js
var object1 = {
 property: "property1"
};

object1.__proto__.property = "property2";
console.log(object1.property); //property1
```

Почему object1 не наследует свойство своего прототипа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ещё как наследует:

```js
var object1 = {
 property: "property1"
};

object1.__proto__.property = "property2";
console.log(object1.property); //property1
delete object1.property;
console.log(object1.property); //property2
```

Так и работает прототипное наследование - если свойства нет в объекте, оно ищется в свойствах прототипа, и так далее, пока не найдём или не кончится цепочка прототипов.

Comment: понял, тоесть он не переопределяет значение свойства которое уже есть в объекте?
всё, понял, спасибо =)

Comment: Наоборот, это объект перекрывает значение прототипа своим. Этот вид наследования - динамический. Обратились к свойству - пошли его искать. Нашли в основном объекте? ок. Нет? Пошли глубже по цепочке прототипов.

Comment: спасибо всем, понял :)

Answer (score 2):

Объекты в JavaScript — динамические "контейнеры", наполненные свойствами (называемыми собственными свойствами). Каждый объект содержит ссылку на свой объект-прототип.
При попытке получить доступ к какому-либо свойству объекта, свойство вначале ищется в самом объекте, затем в прототипе объекта, после чего в прототипе прототипа, и так далее. Поиск ведется до тех пор, пока не найдено свойство с совпадающим именем или не достигнут конец цепочки прототипов.